# How to set query timeout time in RDS postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Can we set the query timeout option in the `AWS` `Postgres` instance?

I know we can do it locally in the configuration file if we have a local setup but not sure about `AWS RDS`.

Any help would be appreciated because due to the above issue CPU utilization is increasing.

Comment: Not sure how different the RDS version is, but in regular Postgres you don't need to edit a config file to achieve that, you can simply run `set statement_timeout  = ...;` to change that value for your session.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can achieve it by creating `Parameter groups` in `AWS RDS`

Please follow below steps.

1. Go to `AWS` Console -> `Amazon RDS`
2. Select `Parameter Group` to create parameter group
   [image]
3. select appropriate version of `Postgres`,provide group name and click on create.
4. Now select the created `Parameter Group` and search the parameter as `statement_timeout`
   [image]
5. Click on `Edit Parameter` button and set the value inside the `Values` box
   [image]
6. Save changes.
7. Now while creating or modifying the database select newly created parameter group.

Comment: If this answer helped you, could you please accept it

Comment: What is the default value, if you don't enter one?

Comment: @user2468842 the default is 0, which is equivalent to no timeout

Comment: Can the same be done per user?